# MS-Access Table Updates to NULL values when calling a Public Function in Update Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

For starters, I am not a professional but I have a few years of SSMS and MS-Access database experience.

Objective:  Update a field in a MS-Access Table through an Update query when calling a Public Function

Issue: When executing the MS-Access query, the field appears to update to a NULL value (this was identified by first updating this field with a text string "testing"; then after executing the query this resulted in NULL values now where it use to say "testing").  If the field is already NULL and then I execute the query, the value remains NULL.  There are results when reviewing the Immediate Window from the VBA after executing the query.

A few of the Expected Results to be in updated Field:

0 years 0 months 0 weeks 4 days 3 hours 11 minutes 8 seconds

0 years 0 months -1 weeks 11 days 21 hours 3 minutes 29 seconds

0 years 0 months -1 weeks 8 days 20 hours 51 minutes 42 seconds

0 years 0 months -1 weeks 12 days 19 hours 43 minutes 17 seconds

0 years 0 months 0 weeks 0 days 0 hours 1 minute 3 seconds

0 years 0 months 0 weeks 0 days 2 hours 30 minutes 55 seconds

0 years 0 months 0 weeks 0 days 2 hours 44 minutes 52 seconds

0 years 0 months 1 week 0 days 1 hour 18 minutes 23 seconds

0 years 0 months 0 weeks 9 days 19 hours 48 minutes 33 seconds

0 years 0 months -1 weeks 11 days 21 hours 6 minutes 49 seconds

Code from Public Function being used:

```vb
Public Function ElapsedTimeString(Interval As String, Date1 As Variant, Date2 As Variant, Optional ShowZero As Boolean = False) As Variant
'You must specify how you want the difference between two date/times to be calculated
'This is done by providing which string from ymwdhns (for years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes and seconds)
'you want calculated.

'For example:
'Print Diff2Dates("y", #6/1/1998#, #6/26/2002#)
'4 years
'Print Diff2Dates("ymd", #6/1/1998#, #6/26/2002#)
'4 years 25 days
'Print Diff2Dates("ymd", #6/1/1998#, #6/26/2002#, True)
'4 years 0 months 25 days
'Print Diff2Dates("ymwd", #6/1/1998#, #6/26/2002#, True)
'4 years 0 months 3 weeks 4 days
'Print Diff2Dates("d", #6/1/1998#, #6/26/2002#)
'1486 days
'Print Diff2Dates("h", #1/25/2002 1:23:01 AM#, #1/26/2002 8:10:34 PM#)
'42 hours
'Print Diff2Dates("hns", #1/25/2002 1:23:01 AM#, #1/26/2002 8:10:34 PM#)
'42 hours 47 minutes 33 seconds
'Print Diff2Dates("dhns", #1/25/2002 1:23:01 AM#, #1/26/2002 8:10:34 PM#)
'1 day 18 hours 47 minutes 33 seconds
'Print Diff2Dates("ymd", #12/31/1999#, #1/1/2000#)
'1 Day
'Print Diff2Dates("ymd", #1/1/2000#, #12/31/1999#)
'-1 day
'Print Diff2Dates("ymd", #1/1/2000#, #1/2/2000#)
'1 Day
 'Description:   This function calculates the number of years,
'               months, days, hours, minutes and seconds between
'               two dates, as elapsed time.

'Inputs:    Interval:   Intervals to be displayed (a string)
'           Date1:      The lower date (see below)
'           Date2:      The higher date (see below)
'           ShowZero:   Boolean to select showing zero elements

'Outputs:   On error: Null
'           On no error: Variant containing the number of years,
'               months, days, hours, minutes & seconds between
'               the two dates, depending on the display interval
'               selected.
'           If Date1 is greater than Date2, the result will
'               be a negative value.
'           The function compensates for the lack of any intervals
'               not listed. For example, if Interval lists "m", but
'               not "y", the function adds the value of the year
'               component to the month component.
'           If ShowZero is True, and an output element is zero, it
'               is displayed. However, if ShowZero is False or
'               omitted, no zero-value elements are displayed.
'               For example, with ShowZero = False, Interval = "ym",
'               elements = 0 & 1 respectively, the output string
'               will be "1 month" - not "0 years 1 month".


On Error GoTo Err_Diff2Dates

Dim booCalcYears As Boolean
Dim booCalcMonths As Boolean
Dim booCalcDays As Boolean
Dim booCalcHours As Boolean
Dim booCalcMinutes As Boolean
Dim booCalcSeconds As Boolean
Dim booCalcWeeks As Boolean
Dim booSwapped As Boolean
Dim dtTemp As Date
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim lngDiffYears As Long
Dim lngDiffMonths As Long
Dim lngDiffDays As Long
Dim lngDiffHours As Long
Dim lngDiffMinutes As Long
Dim lngDiffSeconds As Long
Dim lngDiffWeeks As Long
Dim varTemp As Variant
Dim Diff2Dates As Variant
Const INTERVALS As String = "ymwdhns"

'Check that Interval contains only valid characters
   Interval = LCase$(Interval)
   For intCounter = 1 To Len(Interval)
      If InStr(1, INTERVALS, Mid$(Interval, intCounter, 1)) = 0 Then
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next intCounter

'Check that valid dates have been entered
   If IsNull(Date1) Then Exit Function
   If IsNull(Date2) Then Exit Function
   If Not (IsDate(Date1)) Then Exit Function
   If Not (IsDate(Date2)) Then Exit Function

'If necessary, swap the dates, to ensure that
'Date1 is lower than Date2
'   If Date1 > Date2 Then
'      dtTemp = Date1
'      Date1 = Date2
'      Date2 = dtTemp
'      booSwapped = True
'   End If

   Diff2Dates = Null
   varTemp = Null

'What intervals are supplied
   booCalcYears = (InStr(1, Interval, "y") > 0)
   booCalcMonths = (InStr(1, Interval, "m") > 0)
   booCalcDays = (InStr(1, Interval, "d") > 0)
   booCalcHours = (InStr(1, Interval, "h") > 0)
   booCalcMinutes = (InStr(1, Interval, "n") > 0)
   booCalcSeconds = (InStr(1, Interval, "s") > 0)
   booCalcWeeks = (InStr(1, Interval, "w") > 0)


'Get the cumulative differences
   If booCalcYears Then
      lngDiffYears = Abs(DateDiff("yyyy", Date1, Date2)) - _
              IIf(Format$(Date1, "mmddhhnnss") <= Format$(Date2, "mmddhhnnss"), 0, 1)
      Date1 = DateAdd("yyyy", lngDiffYears, Date1)
   End If

   If booCalcMonths Then
      lngDiffMonths = Abs(DateDiff("m", Date1, Date2)) - _
              IIf(Format$(Date1, "ddhhnnss") <= Format$(Date2, "ddhhnnss"), 0, 1)
      Date1 = DateAdd("m", lngDiffMonths, Date1)
   End If

   If booCalcWeeks Then
      lngDiffWeeks = Abs(DateDiff("w", Date1, Date2)) - _
              IIf(Format$(Date1, "hhnnss") <= Format$(Date2, "hhnnss"), 0, 1)
      Date1 = DateAdd("ww", lngDiffWeeks, Date1)
   End If

   If booCalcDays Then
      lngDiffDays = Abs(DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2)) - _
              IIf(Format$(Date1, "hhnnss") <= Format$(Date2, "hhnnss"), 0, 1)
      Date1 = DateAdd("d", lngDiffDays, Date1)
   End If

   If booCalcHours Then
      lngDiffHours = Abs(DateDiff("h", Date1, Date2)) - _
              IIf(Format$(Date1, "nnss") <= Format$(Date2, "nnss"), 0, 1)
      Date1 = DateAdd("h", lngDiffHours, Date1)
   End If

   If booCalcMinutes Then
      lngDiffMinutes = Abs(DateDiff("n", Date1, Date2)) - _
              IIf(Format$(Date1, "ss") <= Format$(Date2, "ss"), 0, 1)
      Date1 = DateAdd("n", lngDiffMinutes, Date1)
   End If

   If booCalcSeconds Then
      lngDiffSeconds = Abs(DateDiff("s", Date1, Date2))
      Date1 = DateAdd("s", lngDiffSeconds, Date1)
   End If

   If booCalcYears And (lngDiffYears > 0 Or ShowZero) Then
      varTemp = lngDiffYears & IIf(lngDiffYears <> 1, " years", " year")
   End If

   If booCalcMonths And (lngDiffMonths > 0 Or ShowZero) Then
      If booCalcMonths Then
         varTemp = varTemp & IIf(IsNull(varTemp), Null, " ") & _
                   lngDiffMonths & IIf(lngDiffMonths <> 1, " months", " month")
      End If
   End If

   If booCalcWeeks And (lngDiffWeeks > 0 Or ShowZero) Then
      If booCalcWeeks Then
         varTemp = varTemp & IIf(IsNull(varTemp), Null, " ") & _
                   lngDiffWeeks & IIf(lngDiffWeeks <> 1, " weeks", " week")
      End If
   End If

   If booCalcDays And (lngDiffDays > 0 Or ShowZero) Then
      If booCalcDays Then
         varTemp = varTemp & IIf(IsNull(varTemp), Null, " ") & _
                   lngDiffDays & IIf(lngDiffDays <> 1, " days", " day")
      End If
   End If

   If booCalcHours And (lngDiffHours > 0 Or ShowZero) Then
      If booCalcHours Then
         varTemp = varTemp & IIf(IsNull(varTemp), Null, " ") & _
                   lngDiffHours & IIf(lngDiffHours <> 1, " hours", " hour")
      End If
   End If

   If booCalcMinutes And (lngDiffMinutes > 0 Or ShowZero) Then
      If booCalcMinutes Then
         varTemp = varTemp & IIf(IsNull(varTemp), Null, " ") & _
                   lngDiffMinutes & IIf(lngDiffMinutes <> 1, " minutes", " minute")
      End If
   End If

   If booCalcSeconds And (lngDiffSeconds > 0 Or ShowZero) Then
      If booCalcSeconds Then
         varTemp = varTemp & IIf(IsNull(varTemp), Null, " ") & _
                   lngDiffSeconds & IIf(lngDiffSeconds <> 1, " seconds", " second")
      End If
   End If

'   If booSwapped Then
'      varTemp = "-" & varTemp
'   End If

   Diff2Dates = Trim$(varTemp)
Debug.Print varTemp

End_Diff2Dates:
   Exit Function

Err_Diff2Dates:
   Resume End_Diff2Dates

End Function
```

Gooey from MS-Access Update Query:

'************** Code Begin *****************

`UPDATE SupplyToMakeFinal SET SupplyToMakeFinal.TimeToMakeDaysHoursMinutesSeconds = ElapsedTimeString("ymwdhns",[SupplyLatestEndDate],[MakeLatestEndDate],True);`

'************** Code End *****************

I have tried datatype Text and Memo and they both have the same results.

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated as I have spent countless hours researching and trying all I can think of to no avail.

My apologies if my post does not include all that is necessary for your assistance; please let me know if you need anything else from me.

Comment: Ensure that you have `Option Explicit ` at the top of the Module containing your function. (I think you have a naming problem but it's kind of difficult to follow the code on my phone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function works in principle, but it seems you renamed it, but forgot to actually set the return value to the new function name.

You calculate

```vb
Diff2Dates = Trim$(varTemp)
Debug.Print varTemp
' The End
```

But `Diff2Dates` is just a local variable, your function is

```vb
Public Function ElapsedTimeString
```

`ElapsedTimeString` is never assigned, so the function will always return NULL.

Either revert the name change, or add this at the end:

```vb
ElapsedTimeString = Diff2Dates
```

Comment: Andre, thank you, thank you, thank you...technicalities...go figure...I cannot believe I missed this....it works as expected now...again, thanks for the look....

Answer (score 0):

You can't count months this way, as a month can have between 28 and 31 days, neither years as they can have 365 or 366 days. That's why you see negative counts.

So count months using a function like this below. From this you can calculate years (= Int(months / 12)). Add the months to the start date and you have the days count from this date to the end date. Weeks are just seven days.

```vb
Public Function Months( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full months between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of month counts.
' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased stepwise one month from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of months to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2010-03-30. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intMonths As Integer

  ' Find difference in calendar months.
  intMonths = DateDiff("m", datDate1, datDate2)
  ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
  ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a 1 month period
  ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", intMonths, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", -intMonths, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      ' Offset negative count of months to continuous sequence if requested.
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  ' Return count of months as count of full 1 month periods.
  Months = intMonths - intDiff

End Function
```

That said, it still doesn't make much sense to count this way mixing months and days with a resolution of one second. The closest you can get a true count is *days-hours-minutes-seconds(-milliseconds)*.

Comment: Thanks for your review but the code appears to be working fine...the negative are caused due to date1 being prior to date2 hence the negative...i.e. Date1 = #11/25/2015 2:08:34 PM# and Date2 = #11/25/2015 2:00:48 PM# resulting in a negative value which = -1 years 11 months 3 weeks 9 days 23 hours 52 minutes 14 seconds.  I have done my testing on 19,978 date1 and date2 evaluation and I did not find one issue.  Please provide examples of the issue you are referring to please as this may help me understand what it is you are pointing out.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm pointing out that results like "0 years 0 months -1 weeks 11 days 21 hours 6 minutes 49 seconds" doesn't make sense.